# Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Tags} does not match type {Map}] for AWS::SSM::Parameter in YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

The following codesnippet:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Some CloudFormation template

Resources:
  MyResourceName:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: myParameterName
      Type: String
      Value: "somevalue"
      Tags:
        - Key: firstTagName
          Value: firstTagValue
        - Key: secondTagName
          Value: secondTagValue
```

generates the following error in CloudFormation:

[image: Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Tags} does not match type {Map}] for AWS::SSM::Parameter in CloudFormation]

How should I structure the Tags property correctly?

Comment: same issue for AWS::Glue::Job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in the examples of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html.
The structure the Tags property varies by Resource (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html).
For `AWS::SSM::Parameter` Use key-value pairs instead of a Map:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Some CloudFormation template

Resources:
  MyResourceName:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: myParameterName
      Type: String
      Value: "somevalue"
      Tags:
        firstTagName: firstTagValue
        secondTagName: secondTagValue
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: same solution for tags in AWS::Glue::Job (and DefaultArugments take the same approach, maybe wrap those in quotes though)

Comment: So some resources use one syntax for `Tags` and other resources use another syntax? /facepalm

Comment: Or more accurately, sometimes `Tags` is an array and other times `Tags` is a map.

Comment: _"varies by resource"_... Man, this is a pain for newcomers to aws serverless (like me) :(. Struggling with tags (map, list, etc)